# MOSFET discharge (turn off)

Tags: mosfet

I am using the IRF9321 P channel MOSFET for controlling my BLDC motor.
The MOSFET is driven via a transistor which in turn is run by a freescale controller(3.3V pin). Now, when turning it on, it works fine. But, when turning it off its a disaster with the  MOSFET taking almost 5ms to come to '0' Volts.

My circuit is shown below.

[image: MOSFET circuit]

I have been through the datasheet and it says turn off delay time is 180nSecs (approx .1uSecs).

**Am I missing something?**

Comment: I was expecting in micro-seconds, but 5msecs is really bad. Also, will having a diode(schottky) as a Baker clamp reduce the discharge. I have a 0603 reistor. Any suggestions for the Schottky.

Comment: What load have you got connected?

Comment: Hello Sir,
i have got no load.Its just to observe if the voltage comes out fine or not>
I intend to connect a BLDC Motor to it.
Vinod.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I presume you mean 5usec, not 5msec. If it is really 5msec, disregard the below and check for a bad (open) resistor, or perhaps one that is 270K not 270 ohms.

That's not far off what you'd expect discharging the gate charge, which could be relatively large (tens of nanocoulombs) with a 270 ohm resistor.

The MOSFET will only switch in 180nsec if you actually change the gate-to-source voltage fast.

To get it to switch quickly, you could use a gate driver capable of amperes of current such as the [MCP1406/1407](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/22019B.pdf) which will quickly discharge the gate charge.

Comment: Hello Spehro,
Thank u for ur input.Indeed its 5mSecs and not 5uSecs. The drain , I am connecting to the ADC via a voltage divider n/w. The resistors on this line have been removed(making it open). But, I don't see it interfering with the turning off time of MOSFET though.

Comment: No 270R resistor?

Comment: Hello Sir,
I have the 270R. Sorry for confusing u.
I experimented with both 270R and 10K as well.
in both case , surprisingly, its 5msecs. Also, in the base of the transistor I am using almost 4.7K. Do you think that cld be the thing sir.

Comment: Base resistor I don't think will make a difference in terms of milliseconds.

Comment: Sir,
do u think long tracks to the gate will make this happen.
Vinod.

Comment: Definitely not. Something is very high impedance.

Comment: Sir, when u say high impedance u mean something having high im connected to gate of MOSFETR.Right. Also, will transistors cause such behaviour. I mean if the current is not well enough to drive it or turn it on.
I am using the BC847 sir.

Comment: Please answer Andy's comment.

Comment: He asked about the load

Comment: sir, i just did.
I was not using any load. And Andy mentioned that without any load the MOSFET decay time cld easily be a few msecs.

Comment: than u sir for ur inputs.

Answer (score 1):

> I have got no load.Its just to observe if the voltage comes
>   out fine or not> I intend to connect a BLDC Motor to it. Vinod.

Without a load the time delay in switching-off may easily be several milli seconds. Are you operating the two MOSFETs independently - what I mean to say is that if you switched them both in strict time sequence, does the problem also "go-way"?

Comment: hello sir,
Thank u for ur response.
I did not test it that way. The 2 MOSFETs are turned on independently(never together).
But never did i connect a load to it so I will connect a load and test it. I guess its becos of the no load the 5msec delay in discharge.
thank u sir

Comment: Sir, i will link up a strip LED or something else and test it.
i guess it shld behave more like 5uSecs or so decal(which I was expecting in the first place)
Thank u sir :)

Comment: I hope so - good luck

Comment: Hello Sir,
I just toggled the pin with a 10msecs timer(just 1 MOSFET,not both). Again its on no load and the decay is same as before (almost 5 msecs). SO, I guess its because of no load. 
Sir, when u say switch them in strict time sequence, what do you mean - "Turn ON Q1 for t1 with Q2 off" and vice versa or do you suggest turning them both on at the same time(in that case, it will sing a lot of current, I suspect).
Vinod.

Comment: Switch the top FET on (bottom off of course), then switch top off and as soon as this is off (maybe 50 nano seconds later) turn the bottom one on. You should see about a 1us or less decay.

Comment: Hello Sir,
I tried it as u suggested. It works BRILLIANTLY. Now the decay time is almost 4uSecs. Thank u very very much indeed.
Vinod.

Comment: @user6187 Hi Vinod that's good and if you want you can "accept" this answer by pressing a symbol near the up/down arrows.